# Python Telegram bot callback with a custom message not working

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am using Python telegram bot api (https://python-telegram-bot.org/) to reply to commands.

My dispatcher looks like this:

```
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('show', hello, tweet))
```

And callback function is:

```
def hello(bot, update, tweet):
    update.message.reply_text(tweet)
```

But this results in a hang. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.commandhandler.html): The variable `tweet` (whatever that is when adding the handler) will define a filter for your `CommandHandler`.
I have seen filters used only once ([here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/echobot2.py), though this is a different thing in this example I guess), but from my understanding, this only adds an additional rule for the `Dispatcher` object for what kind of updates it will dispatch to that callback function but the `Dispatcher` will still only pass the two arguments `bot` and `update` to that callback function. So I guess the problem is that your callback function `hello` expects three positional arguments but the telegram API under the hood calls it with only two arguments. This will fail even though you as programmer are not notified about that failure.

What is it that you're trying to do in the sense of Expected input when writing a message to the bot user ↔ Expected answer? From the title of this question I am guessing something like `/show message` should be answered with `message`? Something like that can be done with a `MessageHandler` like in the [already mentioned example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/echobot2.py).
Or are you trying to do something different? What shall be passed as parameter `tweet`? Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks @Michael for quick and detailed response. Yes I am replying with a 'custom' message as a response to a user. 'Tweet' in this case is nothing but a string.

Comment: I've gone through the example shared, but I want to send the message when a command is triggered, and not for a non-command reception. In this case 'show' is the command, with no arguments passed from user.

Comment: To see if the problem really is the third parameterof the callback function you could get rid of it and try with some generic text if something is sent when calling via `/show`. If that's the case you should find another way to get the text `tweet` to send instead of putting it as a function parameter for the callback function.